# what is the format of Geometry data type of SQLServer 2008

Tags: geometry, sql-server

I want to know, In which format the Geographic data stored in geometry data type of SQLServer 2008.it looks like a long string,like 0xE6100010466DFEOA4089663524....... for one polygon. My second question is 
How can i get set of google latitudes/longitudes from this data format ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's binary data, you need to use the [STAsText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933977.aspx) method to return it as a string that contains the lat/longs, as in:

```
SELECT [OBJECTID]
  ,[TRACT_ID]
  ,[TRACT_NAME]
  ,[SHAPE].STAsText()
FROM [City].[dbo].[TRACTS]
```

To go the other way, use the [STAsBinary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933881.aspx) method.

Comment: Fine! Thats what i needed. Can i go in reverse. I mean is it possible to convert set of lat/longs back to binary format?

Comment: @user1899 - Yes, see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

> *In which format [is] geographic data stored in `geometry` data type of SQL Server 2008. It looks like a long string, like `0xE6100010466DFEOA4089663524…` for one polygon.*

These values are essentially BLOBs (binary large objects): Values of the `GEOMETRY` and `GEOGRAPHY` types are encoded in a special binary format which is specified in [**"[MS-SSCLRT]: Microsoft SQL Server CLR Types Serialization Formats"**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320529.aspx). (SQL Server 2008 only used version 1 of that format, version 2 was introduced with SQL Server 2012.)

> *How can I get set of Google latitudes/longitudes from this data format?*

This has already been adressed by a previous answer: Call the `.STAsText()` method on a `GEOMETRY`-typed value to get a WKT representation of the geometry. Depending on the projection / coordinate system used by your geometries, this will make lat/long coordinate pairs visible in a plain text format.