# Decode SQL Server encoded locations with PostgreSQL

Tags: coordinate-system, format

I imported the Adventureworks database to PostgreSQL and I can't find a description how to decode the spatial location data - 2 example entries look like this:

```
E6100000010CAE8BFC28BCE4474067A89189898A5EC0
E6100000010CD6FA851AE6D74740BC262A0A03905EC0
```

I tried to cast it with PostGIS to geometry or geography type but I'm getting errors.

```
Adventureworks> select spatial_location::geometry from person.address limit 5;

parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "E6" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

Seems that SQL Server and PostGIS uses different data format but I can't find the description of the one used in SQL Server.
The table can be seen here https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/adventureworks/person/person-for-page/address-p.php

Comment: Looks like the data is binary, you can try the following: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html. WKB: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

Comment: Ogr2ogr can convert geometries and other data from MS SQL https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html into PostGIS geometries https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html but I have seen that users have sometimes problems with  MS SQL. It is not as well known to open source developers than PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/what-is-the-format-of-geometry-data-type-of-sqlserver-2008

Answer (score 0):

With some tinkering I managed to decode it. Original data was a string, code in elixir
In the example I used the address is from Bothell and the coordinates seem to match

```
iex(82)> <<_::binary-size(6), lat::little-float, long::little-float>> =                                                               
...(82)> Base.decode16!("E6100000010CD6FA851AE6D74740BC262A0A03905EC0")
<<230, 16, 0, 0, 1, 12, 214, 250, 133, 26, 230, 215, 71, 64, 188, 38, 42, 10, 3,
  144, 94, 192>>

iex(83)> long
-122.250185528911
iex(84)> lat
47.6867097047995
```

This also works after installing postgis:

```
select st_x(replace(spatial_location, 'E6100000010C', '0101000000')) as long from person.address limit 1
```

As the second param `0101000020E6100000` can be used to set the srid explicit, but the results I'm getting are the same.

```
+------------------+
| long             |
|------------------|
| 47.7869921906598 |
+------------------+
```